# flutter_background_service the service stop working when the app is killed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the flutter package flutter_background_service
the service stop working when the app killed

```
     await service.configure(
androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
  onStart: onStart,
  autoStartOnBoot: true,
  autoStart: true,
  isForegroundMode: true,
  notificationChannelId: 'my_foreground',
  foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888,
),
iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
  // auto start service
  autoStart: true,
  onForeground: onStart,
  onBackground: onIosBackground,
),
```

);
FlutterBackgroundService().invoke("setAsBackground");

service.startService();

Comment: Can you post your full code and androidmanifest file?